# Paddle collision angle

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a breakout game to try to learn Swift. I'm looking to do something similar to what they're doing here - [Breakout Paddle Collision Angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145678/breakout-paddle-collision-angle)

[Picture of angles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGDCZ.png)

Currently, I'm using UIKit Dynamics to track collision behaviors. I have a UIView as a paddle, and a UIView as a ball.

I have no clue how to implement this and I'm wondering how it'd be done in swift. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks